# Any way to transform a block style/CSS to inline CSS?

Tags: html, css, gmail

I'm writing a HTML/CSS email template to be triggered for Gmail and other mails. However, Gmail does not load the `<style>` blocks, so I have to use inline 'style' attribute to make it work.

To illustrate the problem:

```
<style>
    .center {
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>
<a class="center"> text </a>
```

Transform to:

```
<a class="center" style="text-align:center;"> text </a>
```

Does anyone here know a better way or any program for doing it?

Comment: I've had success with premailer, it does what you need

Comment: @aw04 what's that premailer?

Comment: https://github.com/premailer/premailer

Comment: Thats smth I didn't know exists! Cooll!! Do you know any tool like this for java or javascript?

Comment: Actually, this link is the one I used I think. It integrates with grunt task runner. There are other options as well, if you google premailer there are plenty that come up. https://github.com/dwightjack/grunt-premailer

Comment: Looks like there's a gulp one as well, so plenty of automated front end options

Comment: at the agency I worked at we used to use a psd2email service because it was cheaper for the business - they sent psds off and got coded HTML back, it kind of has to be done manually, but it's time consuming and paying UK dev salaries to do it was more expensive then paying a specialist company per psd - you might want to weigh up your time against the cost of using such a service

Comment: @aw04 yep! I found few good options! thanks for those tips! you can answer if you want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a web app which is designed for the job.

> Converts CSS rules into inline style attributes

https://inlinestyler.torchbox.com/

Answer (score 2):

[Premailer](http://premailer.dialect.ca/) is a great tool for generating inline styles and prepping your code for email.

You can even integrate it into your task runner with [grunt](https://github.com/dwightjack/grunt-premailer) or [gulp](https://github.com/justin713/gulp-premailer).